# Adding linked libraries in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to add linked libraries in Xcode 3.2.1 to follow [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/QuickStart/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH22-SW1). The instructions I am following are here

Add the Quartz framework to the project’s target.

1. In the Xcode Groups & Files list, select the QCDemo target.
2. Press Command-I to display the Target Info window.
3. Click General.
4. Under linked libraries, click the plus (+) button. A dialog appears with a list of libraries.
5. Choose Quartz.framework from the list and click the Add button.
6. Close the Target Info window.

I can't see a linked libraries option under General.

Comment: The document you linked to pertains to Interface Builder.

Comment: You begin by creating a project in Xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how the instructions could be any clearer; it's right where they say it should be. Are you sure you're actually selecting the target before bringing up the inspector?

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091216-jfhuyk75s1w7dgdpxg3xwm65ym.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091216-jfhuyk75s1w7dgdpxg3xwm65ym.png)

Comment: Oh, the QCDemo target, not QCDemo